# Bevel/Chamfer algorithm for arbitrary 3D mesh

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, geometry, mesh, model

I can't find any paper about a bevel/chamfer algorithm for 3D mesh. Bevel has a lot of special cases (corners, different bevel profile, bevel larger than a face). I am looking for robustness.
Do you know any algorithm for this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should look into [Medial Axis Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Medial_axis) or [Straight Skeletons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straight_skeleton). They are often used to generate the information you need to bevel things properly. They give you a distance from the bounds of your object at any point in space, which allows you to generate bevels correctly. They are difficult to calculate, though.

You may also want to look into [this paper](http://www.valvesoftware.com/publications/2007/SIGGRAPH2007_AlphaTestedMagnification.pdf) from Valve Software for an alternative way to generate the distance field.